# Error: Failed to open database '/storage/emulated/0/database//db.sqlite'

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio

Trying to create a database and while running this error occurs: `Failed to open database '/storage/emulated/0/database//db.sqlite'`

```
public class G extends Application {
    public static Context context;
    public static String Sdk_Dir= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    public static String App_Dir=Sdk_Dir+"/database/";
    public  SQLiteDatabase database;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context=getApplicationContext();
        File file=new File(App_Dir);
        file.mkdirs();
        if (file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        database=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(App_Dir+"/db.sqlite",null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget the permissions in Manifest file like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: When i want to add external sqlite to my app i have error again do we have permission for that??

Comment: @MohamadAlemi Show me your errorlog. Otherwise i cant suggest anything.

Comment: @MohamadAlemi Did you put your DB to Assets folder?

Answer (score 0):

You have two slashes between "App_Dir" and "db.sqlite", remove one.